# Arch not recognising GPT drive

Tags: arch-linux, gpt

I just finished installing Arch and my 3TB GPT drive (this is not my boot drive) is not showing in arch. I initialised it as GPT on my windows 7 machine and that machine is still able to read from that drive. Does it have to do with UEFI? My mobo is UEFI and my windows installation is installed as EFI. I wasn't sure how to do EFI on arch and some threads mentioned arch would automatically recognise the UEFI BIOS (I am not too sure about the relation between UEFI and OS installation).

Comment: what do you mean by "not showing"?

Comment: I have the boot drive, a second drive and the 2TB drive plugged in. The second drive shows up on my desktop as a mountable drive but not the 2TB drive.

Comment: does it show up if you run `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: Will that affect the content of the drive at all? And will the drive still be accessible on my windows machine after I do that? I am relatively new to Linux so I apologise for not knowing that these commands would do.

Comment: no, `fdisk -l` won't affect the drive at all.  It just lists the partition tables of all drives.  a read-only operation.  and don't apologise for asking - it's smart to ask if you don't understand something.

Comment: I just ran that and I still don't see it.

Comment: is your 3TB drive on the same controller (e.g. built-in SATA connector) as the other drives?  note that some motherboards have one brand of controller for the first few sata ports, and different brand(s) for extra ports.  in some cases, the extra ports may require a different driver (although i would have thought the AHCI driver would work for them all these days)

Comment: All the drives are on the same controller.

Comment: if you boot a rescue cd such as `SystemRescueCD` (http://www.sysresccd.org/) or `gparted`  (http://gparted.org/) does it see the 3TB drive?  testing this will establish whether the problem is due to your bios (or a bios setting) or in your arch install.

Comment: So I revisited the list generated by fdisk -l and I missed something important (I know, I am an idiot). The 2TB is indeed listed and listed as drive sda. And it also gave the following message: "Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary." But that partition seems to be a hidden microsoft reserved partition, so perhaps that maybe the reason.

Comment: try mounting it (readonly if you're worried about messing it up):   `mount -o ro /dev/sdaX /mnt` , where sdaX is the relevant hidden partition device name.

Comment: So sda1 is listed as microsoft reserved (the hidden partition) and sda2 is listed as microsoft basic data. I wasn't able to mount sda1 but I am able to mount sda2 and access all the data that is in it

Comment: If this is of any help fdisk: http://pastebin.com/EbCpXCCL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why the partition isn't showing up on your Arch desktop (IMO GUIs are strange and unreliable and often have annoying hard-coded assumptions<sup>1</sup>) but if the partition is visible to the operating system, e.g. with `sudo fdisk -l` or `sudo blkid` or `sudo lsblk` then you can manually mount the partition anywhere you like.  For example:

```
sudo mkdir -p /windows-data
sudo mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sda2 /windows-data
```

You can, as always, tweak the exact mount options (e.g. for uid, gid, perms) to suit your needs.

You can also cause the partition to be auto-mounted by adding a line to `/etc/fstab`, something like:

`/dev/sda2 /windows-data ntfs uid=1000,gid=1000,noatime,allow_other 0   2`

(that's all on one line, not two lines)

<sup>1</sup> If I had to guess, I'd say that the Arch desktop knows what an "HPFS/NTFS/exFAT" partition is and will display it but doesn't know what a "Microsoft basic data" is, so ignores it.

Comment: How will I know for sure that the drive will always be sda? For example when just my boot drive is connected it is listed as sda but when my other drives are connected my boot drive is listed as sdc and the GPT drive is listed as sda and inside fstab there is a line that mounts sda1 to root already.

Comment: You don't.  That's why you can specify the fs to mount by label or by UUID (Unique Universal ID) as well as /dev/xxxx device name...all modern filesystems have a UUID.  Some also have labels.  `blkid` will tell you both.

Comment: e.g in `/etc/fstab`, instead of a line starting with `/dev/sda2 /windows-data ...` you would have `UUID=xxxxxxxxx /windows-data ...`